# How can we use the the area under $x^2$ to understand the area under $1-x^2$?

Tags: definite-integrals, conic-sections, transformation

> How can we use the fact that
> $$\int_0^2 x^2 = \frac{8}{3}$$
> to compute
> $$\int_{-2}^2 (1 - x^2)dx?$$

I do understand that there is a reflection in the $x$-axis and the original parabola is an even function. So we can double and negate the value of the integral to capture the reflection transformation.

I am unable to understand how do we use the information available to capture the positive shift in the $y$-axis.

Comment: Lookup "linearity of integral".

Comment: ohh yes I can now see it. I should have made use of definitions rather that resort to graphing and understanding in terms of transformations. thank you:)

Comment: The title asks for "area under [the graph of $y=$] $1-x^2$, but part of that graph is itself under the $x$-axis, so it's not clear what is meant by the area under that graph. Whatever it may mean, it certainly doesn't mean $\int_{-2}^2(1-x^2)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Intelligent pauca's comment, linearity of integrals allows us to "take apart" these integrals based on the linear combination of the functions.

We have the integral: $$\int_{-2}^{2}(1-x^2)dx$$

We know that the integral $\int_0^2x^2dx = \frac{8}{3}$, Looking at the graph we can say there is symmetry from the limits of integration. We are integrating $[-2,2]$, and the area under the curve from $[0,2] = [-2,0]$. Since both sides are symmetrical, they have the same area:
$$\int_{-2}^{2} x^2 dx = 2 \cdot\int_0^2x^2dx = 2 \cdot \frac{8}{3} = \frac{16}{3}$$
Now, looking at the other integral we see:
$$\int_{-2}^{2}1dx = (2) - (-2) = 4$$
Putting all the information together we get:
$$\int_{-2}^21dx - \int_{-2}^2x^2dx = 4 - \frac{16}{3} = \boxed{-\frac{4}{3}.}$$